# Binding 2nd onSelectRow handler to jqGrid on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have several pages with jqGrid included, all of which have default onSelectRowEventHandler functions defined.

On some of these pages I want to drop in a partial view (`@Html.Partial("SpecialGridScripts");`) and in the document ready handler, bind a 2nd event handler to selectrow. When the user selects a row, both the original and custom event handlers should fire.

What I have tried so far (doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {

        onSelectAll: function (ids, selected) {
            $(this).triggerHandler("selectAll.jqGrid", [ids, selected]);
        },
        onSelectRow: function (id, selected) {
            $(this).triggerHandler("selectRow.jqGrid", [id, selected]);
        },

    });

    $('#myGrid').bind('selectRow.jqGrid', function (event, id, selected) {
        UpdateVisibility();
    });

});
```

[Based on this jqgrid multiple event handlers example](http://craigcav.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/binding-multiple-event-handlers-to-jqgrid/)

Comment: Why would you not just call the 2nd action from the onSelectRow event?

Comment: To eliminate dependency.

Comment: But you can have the event call each function, they would not be dependent on each other.  I don't mean inside the first function call the 2nd function, I mean inside the event handler.

Comment: I just want the custom stuff to be completely decoupled from the pages - easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this on my own:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    onSelectAll: function (ids, selected) {
        $(this).triggerHandler("selectAll.jqGrid", [ids, selected]);
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id, selected) {
        $(this).triggerHandler("selectRow.jqGrid", [id, selected]);
    },

});

$('#myGrid').on('jqGridSelectRow jqGridSelectAll', function (event, id, selected) {
        UpdateVisibility();
    });
```

});

With jqGrid versions > 4.3.2 it uses jQuery events so I can bind it to jqGridSelectRow and jqGridSelectAll on the fly. I think the solution in the link I posted only applies to jqGrid < version 4.3.2.